# sqlite - query not working when the year changes

Tags: sqlite, strftime

I'm not that good at queries, I've a problem in strftime function.

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) quantity, strftime('%m', CREATED_ON) month FROM OrderItemBIT  WHERE (strftime('%m/%Y',CREATED_ON) BETWEEN '08/2012' AND '01/2013') group by month
```

I dont get any data when i run the above query, even though there are data in those date range,as the years are different.

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) quantity, strftime('%m', CREATED_ON) month FROM OrderItemBIT  WHERE (strftime('%m/%Y',CREATED_ON) BETWEEN '06/2012' AND '12/2012') group by month
```

When i run the above query i get the data in between the date range.

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) quantity, strftime('%m', CREATED_ON) month FROM OrderItemBIT  WHERE (strftime('%m/%Y',CREATED_ON) BETWEEN '01/2013' AND '12/2013') group by month
```

When i run the above query i get the data which is not in the range of that date,as i get data of 2012 year also. The query is just taking the month and not the year.

Can anyone help me to solve the issue!!!

Comment: Can you tell me which strings belongs BETWEEN '08/2012' AND '01/2013'?

Comment: Well, `'12/2012' > '01/2013'` and `'12/2012' < '12/2013'`. That's why  you shouldn't use strings for date comparisons that aren't in a `Ymd` format.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan  NSString *stringdF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld", fromMonthString, fromYear];NSString *stringdT = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld", toMonthString, toYear];

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) quantity, strftime('%m', CREATED_ON) month
FROM OrderItemBIT
WHERE (strftime('%Y%m',CREATED_ON) BETWEEN '201208' AND '201301')
GROUP BY month
```